# What identity does MVC3 app run under?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an MVC3 application.  There is a requirement to allow the user to upload a CSV file, and I need to save it on another server (not the server where the MVC3 app is running).  It seems simple enough to redirect the upload stream to a streamwriter, but the application will have to have permission to the folder on the server where I want to save.

What identity do I have to ask permission for to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What identity do I have to ask permission for to get this done?

An identity that has sufficient privileges to write to the remote server. Don't forget that ASP.NET MVC is an ASP.NET application. So it obeys the same rules in terms of hosting in IIS. You could configure the identity under which your application pool runs in the IIS management console:

[image]

So make sure you have picked an account to which you granted sufficient write permissions to the target folder.